# Configuration Management in a many git repositories

Tags: git, maven, git-submodules

I have the following question: Lets say I have many projects that are mostly independent from each other. All of them are released independently (also different release versions) from each other and they have mostly no code to share. But there are some things which can be shared like a global configuration which can be updated some times from the different projects.
How should I realize it? I thought it would be better to have different git repositories for the projects. But where should I put the configuration? In a submodule? In a subtree? As a dependency? Or should I use one git repo with many maven submodules with different versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would put the global configuration in its own subtree, then graft that subtree on to each of the independant projects.

So that means each project should be in its own repository and then any shared items should be in an additional repository that is a child of each of the separate repositories.

If the configuration is shared but "read-only" use a submodule, and then you can pull the general global config from the shared repo, and then apply any repository specific changes on top.